# Can't get sort/filter/search working with Angular Smart-Table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smart-table

I'm trying to use `st-safe-src` with Smart-Table with ajax data, but clearly I'm doing something wrong. My data is showing in the table, but search, sort, and filter don't work. For some reason Plunker isn't loading for me today, which is unfortunate as that's where several examples are.

My code is below any suggestions would be appreciated.

TransferController.js

```
angular
  .module("RssTransfers")
  .controller("TransferController", ["$http", "$filter", function($http, $filter) {

    var self = this;
    self.all = [];

    function getTransfers() {
      $http
        .get("http://localhost:3000/transfers/api")
        .then(function(response) {
          self.all = response.data.transfers;
          self.collection = [].concat(self.all);
          console.log(self.collection)
          console.log(self.all)
      })
    }
    getTransfers();
}]);
```

table.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div ng-controller="TransferController as transfers">

    <table st-table="collection" st-safe-src="transfers" class="table striped highlight">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="table-head" id="period-col" st-sort="period">Period</th>
          <th class="table-head" st-sort="uploadDate">Upload Date</th>
          <th class="table-head" st-sort="uploadDate">Transfer Code</th>
          <th class="table-head" st-sort="vendor">Vendor</th>
          <th class="table-head" colspan="2" st-sort="description">Description</th>
          <th class="table-head" st-sort="amount">Amount (SSP)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="4">
            <input st-search placeholder="global search" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
          </th>
        </tr>
          <th>
            <input st-search="period" colspan=".75" placeholder="search by period" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
          </th>
          <th>
            <input st-search="uploadDate" placeholder="search by upload date" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
          </th> 
          <th>
            <input st-search="transferCode" placeholder="search by transfer code" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
          </th>
          <th>
            <input st-search="vendor" placeholder="search by vendor" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
          </th>
          <th colspan="2">
            <input st-search="description" placeholder="search by description" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
          </th>
          <th>
            <input st-search="amount" placeholder="search by amount" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="table-cell">
        <tr ng-repeat="data in transfers.all">
          <td class="table-cell" colspan=".75">{{ data.period }}</td>
          <td class="table-cell">{{ data.uploadDate | date }}</td>
          <td class="table-cell">{{ data.transferCode }}</td>
          <td class="table-cell">{{ data.vendor }}</td>
          <td class="table-cell" colspan="2">{{ data.description }}</td>
          <td class="table-cell">{{ data.amount }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used invalid variable names in the top of the table but a correct one in the `ng-repeat`

Change:

```
<table st-table="collection" st-safe-src="transfers">
```

To

```
<table st-table="transfers.collection" st-safe-src="transfers.all" >
```

Comment: Nice catch. Unfortunately nothing happens with smart-table now; it doesn't sort or search. I guess this is better than it clearing everything though.

Comment: Spoke too soon! I am an idiot, I just needed to switch the two. Thanks!